# Documenting all changes in the list of reputation changes: adding deleted questions

Tags: feature-request, reputation, recent-activity

Loss of reputation because a *user is removed* is documented in the list of changes in reputation: loss of reputation because a *a question (answer) is removed* (deleted) is not. On the desktop version, you can reconcile the loss by checking "show removed posts", but not on the mobile (non-app) version.

I fail to see a reason for this asymmetry, and suggest reputation loss from deleted questions (answers) be included in the list of reputation changes.

At the least, if this is not done, the mobile version should have the desktop functionality in this regard; but inclusion in the list strikes me as both more logical and more convenient.

I assume this is site-wide. I noticed it on the math sub-site when I couldn't reconcile on my mobile (iphone) a recent such change.